# mysql4 -> mysql5: LEFT JOIN and implicit join in one Query does not work any longer

Tags: mysql

After upgrading a mysql from 4.1 to 5.6 (with no problems), the problems come when trying to execute the queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1, anothertable 
   LEFT JOIN thirdtable ON table1.id=thirdtable.id 
        AND thirdtable.town=anothertable.town 
WHERE table1.id=8 and anothertable.id=table1.id;
```

ends in the error message:

> Unknown column 'table1.id' in 'on clause'

The same query worked perfectly on 4.11. - any hints what to do, to make the queries work again?
The problem is: there are a lot of queries to rewrite - and they are more complex then the example (which is stripped down to the problem). So it would be nice to find a mysql-server solution.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: There is no "natural join" in your query. You are mixing explicit joins (`JOIN ... ON`) and implicit joins (`WHERE anothertable.id=table1.id`) in the same query which is a very bad habit. You should (and apparently have to) re-write the query to only use explicit joins.

Comment: Sounds like going back to 4.1 again; rewriting isn't possible in this project for several reasons. Thanks for your fast answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "natural join" in your query.

You are mixing explicit joins (JOIN ... ON) and implicit joins (WHERE anothertable.id=table1.id) in the same query which is a very bad habit to begin with.

You should (and apparently have to) re-write the query to only use explicit joins.

You should revisit the "several reasons" that don't allow you to rewrite the queries. It is really a bad idea to keep the queries as they are.